# Java8: double, float literals with suffix in lowercase and uppercase; type constructor and type boxing/unboxing

Tags: java, java-8, primitive

I see that floats and doubles have suffixes in different cases.
So what's the difference in suffix F and f for floats, D and d for doubles ? 
Any history of this behavior ?

Also question about type constructor for example for float type (same behavior for double):
Why can I use "new Float(1L);" and cannot use "new Float("1L");" but "new  Float(1.1F);" and "new Float("1.1F");" - works ok ?

And one more question about autoboxing/unboxing.
Why "float float23 = 1L"; works ok and "Float float12 = "1L";" - not ?

Thanks.

Code example:

```
package com.oca;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class Floats {
    Float float11 = 1.1f;
    Float float12 = 1.1F;

    float float21 = 1.1f;
    float float22 = 1.1F;
    float float23 = 1L;

    Float float31 = new Float(1.1F);
    Float float32 = new Float(1.1f);
    Float float33 = new Float(1L);

    Float float41 = new Float("1.1F");
    Float float42 = new Float("1.1f");
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Floats floats = new Floats();
        System.out.println(floats);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Floats(float11=1.1, float12=1.1, float21=1.1, float22=1.1, float23=1.0, float31=1.1, float32=1.1, float33=1.0, float41=1.1, float42=1.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation. Float(String) leads to Float.valueOf(String), which finally leads to [Double.valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), describing what is accepted and what is not, it provides both textual description and an actual regular expression.

This is how it ends, allowing f, F, d and D only:

```
"[fFdD]?))" +
"[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"
```

It also points out relevant section (3.10.2) of the langspec which (the langspec itself) is a suggested reading anyway, if you are interested in the details of the language.

For the assignment part: you can store integer types into floating point ones, that is why it works. 1L is not a text to parse in runtime, but a text evaluated to a number in compilation time, which can be stored in a float with automatic conversion. The same applies to Float(1L) as it becomes a floating point value (probably a double, but I do not know for sure) even before invoking the constructor (Float has float, double and String constructors only).

Boxing-unboxing is a funny beast, it does no automatic conversion at all, and thus input has to be a float already. Practically you can choose between

```
Float f1=(float)1L;
Float f2=new Float(1L);
```

if you absolutely want to get a Float from 1L.

---

EDIT: if you know the answer, feel free not to ask.

If you open the Java 9 documentation of [Float(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float-java.lang.String-), it says

> Deprecated. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use [...] [valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) to convert a string to a Float object.

Which leads to

> [...] To avoid calling this method on an invalid string and having a NumberFormatException be thrown, the documentation for [Double.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) lists a regular expression which can be used to screen the input.

And link leads to exactly the same description in Java 9 docs, which I have linked for Java 7 (being Java 7 is visible both in the link, and on the page, and as I linked it from the internet, it does not really tell anything about what Java version "I am on"), containing exactly the same excerpt I have quoted here.

Ps: I have not written a word about the JDK source code, and neither have you in the original question. You asked about the why, not the how. In short: because it is specified this way.

Comment: Maybe you're on an older Java version: when I check `Float(String)` constructor (both on Java 8 and Java 9) I see a call to `parseFloat()` in the same class, which calls: `FloatingDecimal.parseFloat()` which calls `readJavaFormatString()` and the result that returns from the latter is converted into a float.

Answer (score 0):

Float constructors expects either float, double or string values (there are different 3 constructors). You're trying to pass a `long` which means that the `long` will be converted to float before the constructor will be called.

When you pass values as strings (to the constructor that expects a string) - it expects that you'll pass a `float` - not a `long` or anything else, that's why you'll get a `NumberFormatException` when you try calling: `new Float("1L")` for example.

*Side-note*: all these 3 constructors will generate deprecation warnings in Java 9, and state that you should use `Float.valueOf()` instead.